# mykey.get() method doesn't work in google app engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I am passing one of my projects to the google app engine, just for the sake of learning. However I have some problems with the ndb datastore. My root entity would be Categories and these have Subcategories as child entities. So let's say I have Category *Foods* which has Subcategory *Main Dishes*. So the key for this Entity would be `ndb.Key(Category, 'Foods', Subcategory, subcategoryId)`. When I am creating a **query object** from this key I can **fetch** the correct subcategory, but from the documentation I would like to do other two methods as well which are not working, I don't know for what reason.

`mySubcategorykey.get()` => it returns None using the aforementioned key.
`Subcategory.get_by_id(subcategoryId)` => Also returns None.

Also when I am generating a safeUrl from the key, I cannot return the object with `ndb.Key(urlSafe=myUrlSafeString).get()`, however printing the `ndb.Key(urlSafe)` gives me the correct key, as it states in the **DataStore Viewer**.

Anyone can help me please telling what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things are wrong here.

Firstly `Subcategory.get_by_id(subcategoryId)` probably won't work as you example key has an ancestor defined.  You need to include the ancestor(s) in get_by_id

Given you are using a `mySubcategorykey.get()` and you don't retrieve an entity then it means the key is incorrect.  a get by key won't experience eventual consistancy so the key is just wrong, or you didn't put() the original entity.

I suggest you examine the key after you put() the entity and see if it actually matches what you are using.

Also there are problems with your example key, `ndb.Key(Category, 'Foods', Subcategory, subcategoryId)`  Category and Subcategory need to be strings, or variables with a string value of "Category" and "SubCategory" - which would be a bit odd to write this way.

Also you don't create query objects from keys , `query` is a method of ndb.Model, or you instantiate a query object from `ndb.Query` .

So you are mixing up some terminolgy and/or concepts.

Comment: Regarding your answer. First: Where it is written in the documentation, that if the entity has an ancestor it needs to be present in the id to make the get_by_id work? (I cannot find that part). Second: As I wrote the get() doesn't work, but when I am doing a Subcategory.query(ancestor=x), and then fetch(y) it works, and I get back the subcategory. The ndb.Key doesn't necessarily has to be a string: [Entities and Keys](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities).

Comment: It pretty much says it in the intro to entities and keys.  If the key was created with an ancestor then it must be supplied to `get_by_id` see the docs for the call `get_by_id(id, parent=None, app=None, namespace=None, **ctx_options)`  other wise it couldn't possibly be fetched, as you don't have a matching key.  And yes the key components can be integers as well.  What you had in your example just didn't make sense.  As I said in the answer, get one of the entities by a query, examine it's key.  The key must match for a get() to work.

Comment: Thank you Tim! It turned out the problem was the key as you said so.